# Including javascript and jQuery code in rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails application I need to implement javascript and jQuery code in final view using app/assets. To create the controller I manually created the program called `tweets_controller.rb` without running the rails generate controller. I am confused where to write my javascript and jQuery code and to make it available in rails final view.

My final view for the two search buttons

```
%=form_tag({controller: 'tweets', action:'index'},  method: "get") do %>
<%=label_tag(:search, "Search for:") %>
<%=text_field_tag(:text) %>
<%=label_tag(:show, "Show for:") %>
<%=text_field_tag(:show) %>
<%= submit_tag( "GO" ) %>
<% end %>
```

My final view for displaying the results

```
<%= will_paginate @tweets %>

<% @tweets.each do |tweets| %>
<ul>
  <li><%= tweets.id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_created_at %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_text %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_name %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_loc %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_img %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.longitude %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.latitude %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.place %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.country %></li>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Since I manually created should I create a file called `tweets.js` in `app/assets/javascripts` folder, if it is so how should I make it available in the views . Please help

Answer (score 0):

add `tweets.js` in `app/assets/javascripts` folder and include that into the view by

```
<% javascript_include_tag "tweets" %>
```

See more [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can include the script in your view (or in the layout file) using javascript_include_tag, but you can also make use of the rails assets pipeline.

If you're using an out-of-the box application.js file (app/assets/javascript/application.js), then by placing your tweets.js in the app/assets/javascript/ your code should be compiled into application.js and then be avaliable for all your views. 
This is because by default, the application.js includes all files within the this directory (require_tree directive).

This is all explained [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline).

To choose which option best suits your needs, I recommend you read [this](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html)